# Storing Application Configuration in AD

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to write a small application that will run on all the domain controllers at my company.

Since all the DCs need to have the same, fairly static config, I thought it might be sane to store the configuration in AD itself. I imagine writing a GUI config editor that manipulates the AD based config.

At first glance, Application Partitions would seem like the right tool for the job.

The first question is: is this just generally a terrible idea? Would pro sysadmins get angry at doing this? Or will this require some high-inertia operation like schema changes?

The second question is: is there a specific object type that would be well suited for storing either JSON blobs or key-value pairs?

And the last question is: Are there better alternatives?

I found a post from a decade ago which touches on this, but things can change rather a lot after 3 major OS releases.

Answer (score 0):

This only might make sense if you were planning on storing configuration for a user on the user's AD object. But even then, anyone in your organization who has access to update AD will be able to change those values in ways that your application may not expect.

> is there a specific object type that would be well suited for storing either JSON blobs or key-value pairs?

No AD attribute is designed for that. At best, you might be able to find a string attribute that has a big enough max length that you could store some JSON value. But performance would be terrible if you want to search for a JSON value using that attribute.

> Are there better alternatives?

Yes. The best solution is to use a dedicated database for your application. You can structure it the way you need, and restrict access to only your application.